# blpop stops processing queue after a while

Tags: php, redis

At my organization, we have a number of redis workers in place for our critical tasks. Usually, once or twice in a day, our workers stop processing the queues.

The code essentially looks like this:

```
while ($item = $redis->blpop(array('someQueue', 'anotherQueue'), 3600)) {
    someFunction();
}
```

If you see, there's not much that is happening in terms of the code, but every once in a while, the queue starts building up and the worker doesn't pop any item from the queue. Setting the timeout for `blpop` is not useful at all because we presume that the problem is with the redis client connection.

At the moment, we have set up a few listeners which alert us when the queue builds up and then we restart the workers but the problem still persists. We can also set a timeout for our redis client, but then again this is not an ideal solution.

- Has anyone else ever faced this?
- What might be the problem?
- Are we doing something wrong?

Our question is similar to [Error in implementing message queue using redis, error in using BLPOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972743/error-in-implementing-message-queue-using-redis-error-in-using-blpop) but we do not get any errors. The worker just stops abruptly.

**Information**

Redis Server: 2.8.2

PHP Redis: [phpredis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis)

### Update #1

The workers which have been running for a long time have stopped processing the queue. After running `CLIENT LIST` we noticed that these workers have a high idle time compared to the rest and their flag is set to `N` instead of `b`. What might be the reason behind this?

### Update #2

The problem was with `someFunction()`. There was a piece of code causing the function to not return control due to which the client was idling for a long time and hence the 'N' flag on running `CLIENT LIST`.

Comment: Hello, "N" means that they are no longer blocking clients, so they are likely not executing a blocking pop operation now. It looks like BLPOP returns, and gets not called again or something like that, which is strange since there is a `while` loop. Maybe `someFunction()` simply never returns?

Comment: It's actually quite strange. We're running the workers with supervisord which keeps reporting them as running and they do not exit just get stuck in blocking state.

Comment: We have put an `echo` after `someFunction()` to check if anything is causing the loop to get stuck in between. Will update when we find something.

Comment: @Aniket did you manged to find solution to your problem ?

Comment: @user3873619 Yes. It was a problem at our end. I have mentioned it as an update in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest verifying if there is an issue and report the problem back to the Redis project as an issue *if* you find something server side. However the following steps will help you to fix the problem even if in some other part of your stack (which is likely, since there are no known problems similar to the one above).

Steps to check what is happening:

1. Wait for one client to stop.
2. Verify that there are actually elements in the list with the `LLEN` command.
3. Check with `CLIENT LIST` that there is actually your client listed, executing a blocking pop (you'll see the command name), and check what is the size of the reply to see if it is that is your client which is not actually consuming the replies it gets.

Random remarks:

1. Redis 2.8.2. is too old, it's advised to upgrade.
2. phpredis may have bugs that could cause this, if it is as old as the Redis server.

Comment: We are trying to simulate the case on our local environment now. Will update here once we are done.

Comment: Updated the question with new observation.

Comment: Found the problem in `someFunction`. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: I was under the impression that the problem was fixed, but the change we made in our function didn't really fix anything. We are still looking into what might be causing this. Will update here if we find anything.

Answer (score -1):

We'd a different problem: if application server loses connectivity with Redis server for a moment, Redis handle becomes invalid (btw, we expect this - this is not a bug). Although your issue is different, the **work around** we used might work for you as well:

You can do something like this:

```
while (true) {
    // The factory method below will check whether handle is valid. If not, create a new one and return
    $redis = MyRedisFactory::getInstance(); 
    $item = $redis->blpop(array('someQueue', 'anotherQueue'), 3600);
    someFunction();
}
```

Comment: From what I have read, the bug you are talking about was fixed long back. In our case, as antirez said, `someFunction()` might be causing for a loss of control return due to which the client keeps idling and stays in "N".