# redis brpop stop process the queue

Tags: python, redis

I choose redis for queue in brpop command. the python script like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        task = rdb.brpop("msg:queue")
        print(task)

    except Exception:
        print("error")
```

anther app will push some msg to the `msg:queue` by `lpush`. I choose supvervisor to run the script. when the script run for some days.

The script still be running, and app still push msg to queue, But, the brpop does't work, it stop processing the queue.

This problem seems like : [blpop stops processing queue after a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540147/blpop-stops-processing-queue-after-a-while). but I have not someFunction.

does it maybe the redis bug, or I use redis for queue in a right way?

Comment: maybe the connection to Redis Server is lost,so check your rdb,is it still alive?Is it a connection pool?

Comment: @pigletfly yes, manerge redis connect use a pool,  the rdb connection is still alive. I try to reproduce this problem. when i kill the rdb connect by `client kill`. the connection will be auto reconnect . It can not be reproduce in kill the brpop connection